# bottle hook before_request not called

Tags: python, bottle

I am not able to use @_local_bottle.hook('before_request').

In a single file scenario where I run bottle from the same file the @_local_bottle.hook('before_request') works:

```
_local_bottle = bottle.Bottle()
def get_bottle():
    return _local_bottle

@_local_bottle.hook('before_request')
def connect_test():
    print("test _local_bottle.hook")
```

But when I start bottle from an start.py where I load all submodules and merge them, the hooks are not called.

```
def start_server(debug=False):
    app, logger = setup_app(debug)
    logger.debug("Importing applications.")
    import ps_web_apps.load_modules

    for module, ps_bottle in ps_web_apps.load_modules.get_bottle_list():
        logger.debug("Importing application '%s'.", module)
        app.merge(ps_bottle)
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, session_opts)
    logger.debug("Starting server.")
    sys.argv[1:] = ["--workers", num_of_workers, "--timeout", gunicorn_timeout]
    if enable_gevent:
        logger.debug("Started as asyc gevent server.")
        bottle.run(app=app, port=8081, server='gunicorn', worker_class='gevent', debug=debug, quiet=not debug)
    else:
        bottle.run(app=app, port=8081, server='gunicorn', debug=debug, quiet=not debug)
```

The strange thing is the the other decorators like "get" do work right beside it:

```
@_local_bottle.hook('before_request')
def connect_test():
    print("test _local_bottle.hook")

@_local_bottle.get('/portal')
def portal():
    logging.debug("log test")
```

Why could the other decorators work, while the @_local_bottle.hook('before_request') is ignored?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a [plugin](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html) instead of a hook? In my experience, Bottle plugins work much more reliably than hooks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint with the Plugin. I already played around with the Plugin. 
My scenario: Bottle, Peewee-ORM, Postgres. There is a Bottle-peewee Plugin. What made it hard was that I really want my models to be in a separate file than the bottle app. I have to try harder to make a Plugin working.